# WPF binded property does not updates source value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have `DependencyProperty` in my custom control. I bound it to some property in some object. When my control appears, it takes value from source and applies it to itself. But when I type something in the input field, source value doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

Control declaration:

```
public class ScriptComponentField : Control
{
    public enum Datatype
    {
        String,
        Integer,
        Real,
        Boolean,
        Enumerable,
        Code
    }

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(Header), typeof(string), typeof(ScriptComponentField), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public object Value
    {
        get { return GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(Value), typeof(object), typeof(ScriptComponentField), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Datatype ValueType
    {
        get { return (Datatype)GetValue(ValueTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueTypeProperty, Value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(ValueType), typeof(Datatype), typeof(ScriptComponentField), new PropertyMetadata(Datatype.String));

    public List<string> EnumerableItems
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(EnumerableItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnumerableItemsProperty, Value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnumerableItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(EnumerableItems), typeof(List<string>), typeof(ScriptComponentField), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    static ScriptComponentField()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ScriptComponentField), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ScriptComponentField)));
    }
}
```

Property `Value` has `object` type just because it can contain any value like `string`, `bool`, `int` and etc.

Control template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ScriptComponentField}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ScriptComponentField}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" SharedSizeGroup="name"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="value"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="InputString" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2"/>
                    <Advanced:IntegerUpDown x:Name="InputInteger" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="1" Value="{TemplateBinding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="InputBoolean" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ValueType" Value="String">
                        <Setter TargetName="InputString" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ValueType" Value="Integer">
                        <Setter TargetName="InputInteger" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ValueType" Value="Boolean">
                        <Setter TargetName="InputBoolean" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: MaxB has provided a good guess from the limited information available; but you ought to boil this problem down to a [MCVE]. By doing so you might find and it yourself. If not, by giving a repeatable problem, others can help you solve it. But not like this.

Comment: Now I provided a complete description of the class and style of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `TemplateBinding`. `TemplateBinding` is always `OneWay`. If you change your `TemplateBinding` to the `TwoWay` `Binding` with `RelativeSource` or with `ElementName` it will work.

```
<TextBox x:Name="InputString" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:ScriptComponentField}, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2"/>
```

Comment: `{TemplateBinding Value}` -> `{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:ScriptComponentField}, Mode=TwoWay}` in template works well. Thank you.

Comment: @PurpleDragon Thank you for the hint, have forgotten to write it in code ;)

Comment: As said, setting `Mode=TwoWay` is redundant. It is the default mode for the Text property.

Comment: But maybe for another types it can be useful.

Comment: You mean another property? Sure. But the question is about TextBox.Text.

Comment: Also better use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`.

Comment: I also replaced `new PropertyMetadata(null)` with `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)` in control declaration to make `TwoWay` binding mode default for it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed the "Mode=TwoWay" property, as follows:

```
<Button x:Name="btnMy" Content="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Default control binding is "OneWay" (See EDIT below), which "Updates the binding target (target) property when the binding source (source) changes." © MSDN link below

TwoWay Binding: "Causes changes to either the source property or the target property to automatically update the other" © MSDN link below

[MSDN BindingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT:

As noted by Clemens, regarding the default binding mode:
"The default mode is set during registration of a property, by FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions." © Clemens
Is short, it isn't always OneWay, but most of the times.

Comment: It doesn't help.
My xaml tag: `<Controls:ScriptComponentField Header="Author" Value="{Binding author, Mode=TwoWay}" ValueType="String"/>`

Comment: What control is that? I suppose that your "input field" is not connected to the "author". Do you see the text of the author, then change this text, and nothing happens? Or do you see the text of author, then insert text somewhere in any other different place and expect author to change? Sorry, I feel like I'm missing something

Comment: It connected via `DataContext` property. When I run the application, I see that the field has received a value from the `author` in the `DataContext`. If `ValueType`="String", the `TextBox` with `Text` binded to `author` is displayed. When I write anything in this `TextBox`, it does not affect the original value in `DataContext`.

Comment: @PurpleDragon is your "author" a property by itself? (does it have get;set;)? I'll run some checks meanwhile to see why it can happen

Comment: Note that it is incorrect to say the "*default control binding is OneWay*". The default binding mode actually dependends on the target property. While for most of them the default mode is OneWay, there are also others, like the Text property of TextBox. Its default binding mode is TwoWay. The default mode is set during registration of a property, by FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.